# What's the difference between PROC EXPORT, LIBNAME and ODS in exporting file?

Tags: sas

Basically, I understood I can export files and data from SAS in three ways (PROC EXPORT, LIBNAME statement and ODS statement), but I really can't see the differences between them.

From what I understood, the PROC EXPORT let me export only data sets created using a DATA step, but not the results of the procedures.
Differently, LIBNAME and ODS statements allow this, but it seems there isn't a significant difference between them.

Is this correct? And if it's so, what's the main difference between the two statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ODS redirects output from the procs directly to a different output format, such as PDF, Excel, Word or PowerPoint. This is more for generating automated reports that have styles and formatting which differentiates it from PROC EXPORT or LIBNAME.

PROC EXPORT exports raw data - no formatting or commenting - best used for data transfers. 
LIBNAME is closer to export - you get more raw data extracted but not formatting in the data. I don't think there's a significant difference between PROC EXPORT and LIBNAME methods.